# Allow rearranging of before/after posts in suggested edit queue

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

Currently, it appears that the before and after posts within the Suggested Edit queue must be side-by-side. It makes it hard, however, to detect some code formatting changes, since spaces (used to format as code and to indent said code) make it very difficult to read.

[image]
I suggest having an option that lets the user switch between the side-by-side view and a view where the old post is on top, new is on bottom.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a screenshot of the one review that prompted this thought. I can try to get one tomorrow once I can review more suggested edits.

Comment: You can do better than that: get a link to that review item by looking at your review history (http://stackoverflow.com/users/899126/chrisforrence?tab=activity&sort=reviews)

Comment: @Mat [...huh.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3rhQc666Sg) Updated question.